# What is the meaning of syntax <<<XML XML in this example "https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php"?

Tags: php, xml

As I mention in the title, i am not sure what is <<<XML ...  XML. It likes some open/close tag in HTML tags.
[image]
And i wonder how many type of these tags?

Do we have <<<HTML ...HTML?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe this is heredoc notation to make a multiline string literal, but it's hard to tell since I can't see the end of the string.  It should end in EOF.  See the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: The `XML` after `<<<` is an arbitrary character sequence. You can use `<<<MY_MULTILINE_STRING` and should close the heredoc string with `MY_MULTILINE_STRING;` in a line whitout any character before the string.

Comment: Thanks ChrisStrickland, Selim. I got it